# showing existence and uniqueness of solution of $y'(t)=\frac1{1+|y(t)|}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Given \begin{align*}
y'(t)&=\frac1{1+|y(t)|},&y(0)=y_0&&\textrm{for }t\in[a,b] 
\end{align*}

I want to show that this IVP has a unique solution

My attempt: We get $f(t,x)=\frac1{1+|x|}$. If $f$ is continuous there exists a solution on $[a,b]$ by Peano. If $f$ is Lipschitz-continuous, the solution is unique.

Since fractions and $|\cdot|$ are continous and $|\cdot|\geq0$, $f$ is continuous and so there exists a solution by Peano, right?

Now showing Lipschitz-continuity: $$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|=\left|\frac1{1+|x|}+\frac1{1+|y|}\right|=\left|\frac{1+|y|+1+|x|}{(1+|x|)(1+|y|)}\right|$$

but now I am stuck. How do you get $\leq L|x-y|$ ?

Comment: You can also use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You wrote $+$ instead of $-$ in the expression for $f(t,x)-f(t,y)$. It should be
$$|f(t,x)-f(t,y)|=\left|\frac1{1+|x|}-\frac1{1+|y|}\right|=\frac{\left||x|-|y|\right|}{(1+|x|)(1+|y|)} \le \left||x|-|y|\right| \le |x-y|.$$